# Can I edit my previous questions citing names of hospitals,medical research institutes and name of the city.?

Tags: discussion

This question is about our family members who visited various hospitals,medical research institute,cancer research institute for check up,diagnosis and hospitalization.can I cite the names of the hospitals,research institutes and the name of the city I live in as parts of my edit??Will my edits,comments be valid if I include above?

Answer (score 3):

First, please notice that I moved your question to this meta site for MedSci. This is where you can ask questions about how the site operates, make suggestions, or almost anything else. The main site is for medical science questions only.

One of your questions was closed because it asked for personal medical advice, which is strictly off topic here. We do not and will not provide medical advice. See [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748) for an explanation of why. Your other question was closed as being unclear what you're asking, so adding hospital names and such won't help. It won't get either question reopened. There's no way to get the medical advice question reopened, but you can possibly get the other one reopened by editing it and clarifying your question. I was completely unable to determine what you were trying to ask.

But before you do anything and before you ask more questions, please visit the [Help Center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help) and learn how the site works. In particular please read [this section](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and learn what questions are welcome here.

Comment: --all the patients except me are dead. I do not want any advice which goes against your rules.I have read the meta site and help center rules.Thank you..  user-26375[ABHIJIT BAGCHI]